# Unknown lifecycle phase in maven when specifying a revision

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I'm new to maven and I'm having some issues building some code. A colleague uses the following command to build one of our projects:

```
mvn clean install –Drevision=5.0.0-local-SNAPSHOT –P bld
```

This works on his machine but not on mine. I get

`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "▒Drevision=5.0.0-local-SNAPSHOT".`

Any idea what is could be causing this? I use Maven version 3.6.3 with java 1.8.0_92. Also how do I make a run configuration on Eclipse for the command line above? Do I just just remove "mvn" and add the rest to the "Goals" field?

Comment: In the Maven run configuration the goals are `clean install`, the profile is `bld` and the parameter named `revision` has the value `5.0.0-local-SNAPSHOT`. Does this fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `-` at the beginning of `-Drevision=...` is not a real `-` but some other dash.

Try not to copy/paste, but enter it directly.

howlger already answered the part about Eclipse.